# Как сделать обратный отсчет времени в java swing?

Tags: java, swing

Написал небольшую программу в java используя swing. В одном месте, программа должна выводить в jTextfield отсчет секунд от 3 до 0, затем сообщение старт. Пытался с помощью такой конструкции:

```
for(int i = 3, i > o; i--)
{ jTextfield.setText("Осталось: " + i);
Thread.sleep(1000);
 }
```

Все это приписывалось внутри jButton, т.е. при нажатии мышкой на кнопку jButton. Короче, вся программа висела эти самые 3 секунды, а потом в jTextfield вышло 1, и все на этом. Также пытался с Timer и TimerTask, но там тоже не срослось. Как мне решить эту проблему, помогите а.

Answer (score 1):

При создании окна создаётся [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), внутри которого крутится бесконечный цикл, на каждой итерации достающий событие из очереди и запускающий обработчик для него. В обработчике бесполезно использовать циклы для изменения интерфейса, так как все изменения просто встанут в очередь и будут выполнены только на одной из следующих итераций цикла событий. И тем более нельзя останавливать *Поток Обработки Событий* (что вы делаете вызовом Thread.sleep(1000)), это заморозит всё приложение. Поэтому необходимо использовать предлагаемые библиотекой механизмы запуска фоновых задач и взаимодействия с ними. Например такие, как [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-), [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) и [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Countdown {
    private final JLabel label = new JLabel("...");
    private final JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
    private final Timer timer;
    private int count = 3;

    public Countdown() {
        timer = new Timer(1000, e -> {
            if (count > 0) {
                label.setText(String.valueOf(count--));
            } else {
                ((Timer) (e.getSource())).stop();
                count = 3;
                button.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);

        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            timer.start();
            button.setEnabled(false);
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Countdown();
    }
}
```